# array losing scope when moved into a for ( in ) loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

This is really driving me crazy.  Why does my array lose scope moving it into a for loop?  Please have a look at this code, the var 'marker' is losing scope near the beginning of this script. ANY thoughts welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
//var cell={}; 
var cellcenter = new Array();

var lat = ''; var lng=''; 

$(document).ready(function(){
    i=0; 
    $.getJSON('http://www.perivision.net/testing/containment/containment.php', function(data) {
        var marker = new Array();
        marker[0]=9;
        $('#output').html('this works '+marker[0]);
        for (index in data) {
             i++; 
             $('#output').html(' this does not '+marker[0]);
            for (element in data[index]) {

                //console.log(element);
                //console.log(data[index][element]);
                if (element=="attribute8"){
                    lat=data[index][element];
                }
                if (element=="attribute9"){
                    //cell[i]=data[index][element];
                    lng=data[index][element];
                    cellcenter[i]=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
                    var mapOptions = {
                      zoom: 4,
                      center: myLatlng,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    }

                    var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOptions);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        title:"Hello World!"
                    });
                    marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: cellcenter[i],
                        title:"Hello World!"+i
                    });

                    // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
                    marker.setMap(map);
                    //marker[0].setMap(map);
                    marker[i].setMap(map);
                    //$('#output').html('re '+marker[0]);
                    //console.log('ping '+i+' '+cellcenter[i]);

                }
            } 
        }

    });

}); 
function donothing(){


    }               


</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
 <button id="requestDataBtn">Get Data</button><br /> 
 <div id='output'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "losing scope" mean?

Comment: when you create a variable inside a function, say, i=0;  This 'i' will equal 0 inside that function.  You can have another function where you define 'i' and it will be treated separately.  That is scope.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson. But what does ***"losing"*** scope mean?

Comment: Is the content of marker is getting modified?

Comment: there is no problem with the scope, it is working with me, check your code, maybe there is a syntax error or something that stops the execution of the code ( or maybe data is empty or not null which is the most probable ) http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/gaWwA/

Comment: wait, it works?  Both $(#output.. ) statements give a value and not an undefined?

Comment: @deceze   Oh sorry, what I mean is the varible 'marker' is undefined instead of '9' once it enters the loop.  I'm guessing it lost object type of array() once it entered the loop.

Comment: WTH???  Now its working...

Comment: I cannot give a reason why its working now. Perhaps an issue with Chrome and cache? All I did is change marker to markerArray and then change the second html jquery call from .html to .append. Now it works. Thanks everyone, I wish my solution was less black magic and something that makes sense.  In 7 hours I will answer and close this out.

Comment: course, this is only 1/2 of the battle. Now I need to understand why I'm not getting 4 markers.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > var marker = new google.maps.Marker

This is your problem. You are giving the same name `marker` to some other object. Now, Javascript interpreter scans the entire JS code and looks for any `var` definitions before executing. Thats why eventhough you have defined `marker` mch below it still get reset.

Comment: I tried changing marker to markerarray, same problem  The first $(#output..) works, the second does not.

Comment: Can you repost your code with the changes ?

Comment: I will, however after making a second change, where I changed to jquery request from .html to .append, it started working.  Its fully possible that there was a caching hang up or something else that kept my first change from working.  its seems you were correct.  Now i just need to figure out why I'm not getting 4 markers.